# How does parameter mode in resize function from scikit-image library work?

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image

I have come across the `resize` function from a snippet given below. I am a bit confused with the parameter `mode` in `resize` function. To understand more about it, I have looked at the scikit-image documentation.

```
 # snippet  
 for n,id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_ids),total=len(train_ids)):
    # get the path
    path = train_path + id_
    # read the image
    # The code ignores the 4th channel Any particular reason behind it ?
    img = imread(path+'/images/'+id_+'.png')[:,:,:image_channels]
    # Resizes a image to match a certain size 
    img = resize(img,(image_height,image_width),mode='constant',preserve_range=True)
    # Assign the image to X_train
    X_train[n] = img
    # mask is one channel
    mask = np.zeros((image_height,image_width,1),dtype=np.bool)
```

The documentation says

> Points outside the boundaries of the input are filled according to the given mode. Modes match the behaviour of numpy.pad.

So I googled more about it. And I came to know, it has to do something with padding. The possible choices for the mode parameter are

```
   {‘constant’, ‘edge’, ‘symmetric’, ‘reflect’, ‘wrap’}.
```

Am more curious to know through examples, how each one differs from the other?. I am a bit sceptical about the tags added to this question. Please pardon me.